How is the universe still expanding if the seven heavens have already been made?
It is known that the earth and heavens have already been made in 6 days. The lowest heaven is our observable universe. In Quran 51:47, it is written “We built the universe with ˹great˺ might, and We are certainly expanding ˹it˺.” So my question is that if the heavens and earth have already been made, how is it that it’s still expanding. Same with earth, as it’s already been made how is it still undergoing changes today? Jazakallah Khair

Allah created the system and system is functioning. It's like saying Allah created Adam and eve how come human still coming to existence.
Allah created everything heaven and earth and everything in between in 6 days. That doesn't mean after 6 days he stopped creating. Stars are still forming, new new planets still forming, so is mountains etc.
Sec, what does universe expending has to do with creation. It can expend even if the creation is complete.
Maybe I misunderstood your question but hope I was able to answer

Jazakallah Khair brother

Ofcourse there is a certain lack of understanding we have about the universe and how everything exists beyond it.
Some could theorise that the universe has a set amount of space, or the heavens themselves also expand, or that the universe continues to expand while still being contained in the heavens (as on heaven is like a ring in the dessert inside of the heaven above it)
To be fair, I can't remember if that was the description of each heaven, or just the throne of Allah compared to thee heavens.
But I can say that the universe expanding is something we can rule out. When we say it expands, it means it expands in space but isn't increase in energy / matter (except energy can convert to matter and matter to energy in some theories). But beyond that, the universe is just expanding in space.
Allah knows best, maybe I am wrong since there will always be a level of ignorance us humans will have.
Regarding the earth, it's changing in shape and axis. Idk what else to say

#1, What is expanding is the observable universe, and not necessarily all of the universe as it could possibly be. We even don't know much about the dark energy and matter, and we are not sure even if they really exist, as there are theories to explain the observations differently
#2, What Allah means in Quran is Ontic knowledge, that is the truth as it is, but what we understand of Allah's words in Quran is Epistemic knowledge affected by out presumptions and accepted theories. What scientists think to know about universe or any other aspect of nature is as well Epistemic understanding of observations, and even observations are not really observations alone, but are sometimes affected by the glasses the observer wears and looks through. Thinking about what it appears to have been meant in Quran with what scientists think to be valid at the time, is a place for controversy. We can try to resolve the issue but there will always remain several ifs ...
#3, the concept of time in some Muslim philosopher's ideas is somewhat tied to the concept of motion, and the creation of a motion is somewhat viewed as the creation of each instant of the motion individually, like a movie comprises several photos in a specified order. So that each instant of time stands for an individual creation of the whole universe with all its details (لبس علیٰ لبس). This is different than how e.g. Jews used to look at creation that the God created the universe and then let it work and He Himself took a rest ... Not to mean this view is certainly meant by Allah, Ontically, but trying to show that there is no necessary contradiction between something being created and being as well changeable in the course of time. Even you can consider instead the rules of Physics (the objective versions if there exist any, and not the subjective versions declared and widely accepted by scientists of the present time), a constraint limited version of Allah's Sunnah, so that e.g. physical causality chains being a subset of the general causality; and if that is so, the rules themselves will be created as a art of the creation of things, like assuming Allah has created Electron and how it will interact with Protons and other Electrons. This way, evolution of anything will be an aspect of the creation of that thing.
You might be able to continue this way of thinking ... the answer provided has not been tried to be inclusive.
